# Postfix not starting. How to resort to default settings?

Tags: ubuntu, webmin, virtualmin

I just changed this "Use TLS for SMTP connections" and I turned inet_protocols = all to inet_protocols = ipv4 and then back to what it was.

Reloaded the configuration a couple of times.

Now, it won't start.

Please help. I am a layman just trying to set up my own email server.

**Ubuntu/Webmin/Virtualmin**

Answer (score 1):

Always have a copy of your original configuration files before starting to edit.

If you messed up the configuration, rollback the changes you made on config file and reload.

That should do the trick, otherwise remove the files and reinstall Postfix.

Comment: Right, how do I remove and install again? Can you please guide me to it or any documentation please?

Comment: $sudo apt-get purge postfix

----->$sudo apt-get autoremove postfix 

----->$sudo apt-get install postfix